# Is there a way to send messages from my account to other user in telegram using nodejs without the use of bot?

Tags: node.js, automation, telegram, telegram-api

I have created a bot in telegram and am using it to perform some basic automation. Recently I was trying to send data from another bot to my original bot to add new function to bot, But found out bot don't respond to messages from other bots. Is there a way to send messages from nodejs as user or without it being labeled as bot so other bot can read it. I cannot add explicit bot command because I need the msg to be transmitted as is.

I initially thought it was possible using telegram api but reading through the doc I realized the messages sent using the api also come off as being sent by bot. Now I am stuck and have no other ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, without a bot there is no chance for now.In order for you to send users messages on telegram you would need to create your own telegram bot and than you can send messages.